# Join two SQL queries together but using a variable from the frist query to perform the second

Tags: sql, mysql, join, subquery, union

I'm trying to perform an SQL query in MySQL, and then right join the column of the second query.

However, in order to perform the second query I need a variable from the result of the first (the employee number).

This example displays the employees in a particular team, but also ads a column that shows how many times that employee in that row has failed to turn up for a shift.

The employee log table only holds the employee id number and whether they showed up or not to their shift.

employee.id_number is the PK for employee table and the FK for employee_log table

```
SELECT employee.id_number, employee.name, employee.surname 
FROM employee 
WHERE employee.team_name = "alpha";

Select count(employee_log.attendance_type) 
FROM employee_log 
WHERE employee_log.attendance_type = "No-Show";
```

AND match with the returned employee.id_number from the 1st query....then join this column onto the right of the query above....right inner join?

Maybe an inner join operation or sub query?

Comment: show me a query where you return the employees ID from the employee_log table.

Answer (score 0):

Below query should help If I get it correct.

```
Select count(employee_log.attendance_type) 
FROM employee_log log
JOIN (
    SELECT employee.id_number, employee.name, employee.surname 
    FROM employee 
    WHERE employee.team_name = "alpha";
) emp ON emp.id_number = log.id_number
WHERE employee_log.attendance_type = "No-Show"
```

Comment: Hi Rahul,  thanks for your response, however this only returned the count column.

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like you're after is a join.  There are multiple join types:

- INNER JOIN  (Both tables have to have the data)
- LEFT JOIN (all records from the LEFT table and those that match on right)
- RIGHT JOIN (All records from the RIGHT table and those that match from left)
- FULL OUTER ( All records from both tables aligning where they match)
- CROSS JOIN (All records from both tables related to each other (5 records in 1 table, 10 in another produces (5*10) 50 records)
- OUTER APPLY (A table value function which will return the results of a sub query for each record in the outer.  For example, maybe I want the top 10 newest log entries for each employee we could select top 10 and correlate the employeeIDs; but you don't need this here)
- UNION, MINUS, EXCEPT, UNION ALL, INTERSECT... are all SET operators and not technically joins.  They evaluate data sets as a whole against other data sets. UNION combines both sets and eliminates duplicates, EXCEPT/MINUS removes data from first set found in second, and intersect shows where they exist in both sets.  UNION ALL combines both and keeps Duplicates.  The set operators do not seem germane to your question.

**Assumption**

- employee_log has a field called id_number which is a foreign key to employee.id_number
- we use coalesce in case any employee in alpha has NO entries in the log table.  In this case we want 0 to be displayed instead of NULL

Notes:

- aliased tables for improve readability (E) for employee (EL) for Employee Log
- used LEFT join (include all records in Employee Table, and only those that match in the employee Log.
- applied filter on attendance_type on the join itself.  If we put this in the where clause it would negate the left join making it behave like an inner join.
- Left join, right join it's about the order of the tables.  So we want to show all alpha team employees and the # of times they didn't show up.

Process:

- System retrieves all employees of 'alpha' team
- System gets all logs files of 'no-show' associated to an employee of alpha
- system counts those entries of no-show grouping by the ID, first, last names
- system renders output

Query:

```
SELECT E.id_number, E.name, E.surname, coalesce(count(EL.attendance_type),0) as NoShows
FROM employee E
LEFT JOIN employee_log EL
  on E.id_number = EL.id_number
 AND EL.attendance_type = 'No-Show'
WHERE E.team_name = 'alpha'
GROUP BY E.id_number, E.name, E.surname
```

Comment: Hi xQbert thanks for you detailed response, Tried your solution, Looks like i'm getting an error where the 'on claus' is:  #1054 - Unknown column  E.id_number in 'on clause'

Comment: that's really odd... E is in reference to `employee` table.   and `id_number` is in reference to the PK of that table.  Can you confirm `employee.id_number` exists as well as `employee_log.id_number`?  Also confirm what RDBMS and version this is... perhaps the ANSI 92 isn'ta available on your RDBMS... (Relational database management system)  mySQL what version...

Comment: Actually sorry my bad its 10.4.24-MariaDB

Comment: No problem; but that supports ANSI 92 standards... so the join should be fine...  maybe model up teh tables here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4 so we can see it with sample data and try and recreate the error  the only other difference is my use of ' vs " in the variables.... but either should be fine...

Comment: Seems to work for me... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=8b012dc16b251ae8bd82ba1f261e962c  this is 4.22 so 4.24 shoudl work as well...

Comment: So this means either I don't know your table structure, it's not what I suspect it to be; or I have a column name spelled differently than you to.

Comment: Hi xQbert,  it's my fault I think a missed out a chunk of detail.  I'm so sorry for stuffing you around.  There were a few more tables being joined together that i forgot to mention, these tables simply share the same PK and I just join these using something simple like E.id_number = EL.id_number in the WHERE clause for those joins.  Would the extra tables have thrown a spanner in the works of your example?  maybe i could recreate my example, but I can understand if your frustrated that I failed to mention this. thankyou so much for your help regardless it was very kind of you.

Comment: yes more tables depending on join type and data/no data could cause records to not be returned.  If you want to set up a minimally complete verifiable example in one of those fiddles, we could then see the problem and I could revisit it for a complete solution.